# JavaFX PixelWriter low performance

Tags: java, swing, javafx, imageview

I created a simple JavaFX image editor. There are two instances of ImageView (on for the original image and one for the edited one).
A method converts the WritableImage to grayscale.
The problem is, the conversion takes approximately twice the time Swing needs to do the same task. Any idea why?

```
@FXML
void loadImage(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Main.primaryStage);
    if (file != null) {
        Image image = new Image("file:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        imViewOrig.setImage(image);
        PixelReader pr = imViewOrig.getImage().getPixelReader();
        WritableImage wi = new WritableImage(
            pr, 
            (int)imViewOrig.getImage().getWidth(), 
            (int)imViewOrig.getImage().getHeight());
        imViewEdit.setImage(wi);
    }
}

@FXML
void greyscale(ActionEvent event) {
    PixelReader pr = imViewOrig.getImage().getPixelReader();
    PixelWriter pw = ((WritableImage)imViewEdit.getImage()).getPixelWriter();
    long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int x = 0; x < imViewEdit.getImage().getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < imViewEdit.getImage().getHeight(); y++) {
            Color c = pr.getColor(x, y);
            double avg = (c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c.getBlue()) / 3.;
            Color grey = new Color(avg, avg, avg, c.getOpacity());
            pw.setColor(x, y, grey);                
        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime + "ms");
}
```

Swing code:

```
public void greyscale() {
    long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
            int avg = (c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c.getBlue()) / 3;
            Color grey = new Color(avg, avg, avg);
            image.setRGB(x, y, grey.getRGB());                
        }
    }
    repaint();
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime + "ms");
}
```

Comment: As an alternative implementation, you could apply a [ColorAdjust](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) effect to desaturate the color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a quick test, it works of the order of 10 times faster if you just do the `int` computations, instead of manipulating `Color` objects. The JavaFX `Color` class is a substantially richer implementation than the AWT `Color` class; I guess this comes at a cost of additional overhead.

```
    int width = (int)image.getWidth();
    int height = (int)image.getHeight();

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    WritablePixelFormat<IntBuffer> pixelFormat = PixelFormat.getIntArgbPreInstance();
    pr.getPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixelFormat, pixels, 0, width);

    int[] newPixels = new int[pixels.length];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        int c = pixels[i];
        int a = c & 0xFF000000 ;
        int r = (c >> 16) & 0xFF ;
        int g = (c >> 8) & 0xFF ;
        int b = c & 0xFF ;
        int gray = (r+g+b) / 3 ;
        newPixels[i] = a | (gray << 16) | (gray << 8) | gray ;
    }

    pw.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixelFormat, newPixels, 0, width);
```

Comment: Perfect, does Swing have anything similar?

Comment: I think most of the low level primitives of Swing around images are in the awt classes.  The closest thing to the JavaFX [`PixelWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html) would seem to be the [`java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/MemoryImageSource.html). Disclaimer: I don't know much about Swing.

Comment: I also have forgotten most of my Swing/AWT skills, but you could try just modifying your existing code to avoid creating the `Color` object. There is a `BufferedImage.getRGB(...)` which fills an `int[]` with the pixel data; you can extract the red, green, and blue components in the same way as in the JavaFX code (there is no alpha component), and then map into a new array and call `BufferedImage.setRGB(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

[`ColorAdjust`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/effect/ColorAdjust.html) based sample which converts a color image to monochrome by desaturating it when you mouse-over the image.

Given appropriate hardware (which is available to most systems JavaFX runs on), the JavaFX runtime may perform some of the implementation of the color adjustment in hardware, which might lead to a more efficient implementation than manipulating pixels using a [`PixelWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html).

[image: color]
[image: monochrome]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Shadow extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Image image = new Image(
                "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/smurfs-movie/512/smurfette-icon.png"
        );

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        ColorAdjust monochrome = new ColorAdjust();
        monochrome.setSaturation(-1.0);

        imageView.effectProperty().bind(
                Bindings
                    .when(imageView.hoverProperty())
                        .then(monochrome)
                        .otherwise((ColorAdjust) null)
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(imageView), Color.AQUA));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```